# How can I go to Perperikon by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, sightseeing, bulgaria, perperikon, archaeology

I would like to visit [the ancient city of Perperikon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perperikon) in Bulgaria. It's no problem at all to go to [Plovdiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plovdiv) or [Kardzali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardzhali), but are there any public transport from there to Perperikon? How much would cost a taxi from Kardzali to Perperikon?

Google is showing a wrong place, here is a better map:[image]

Comment: If one is to believe Google it's a 2km from Kardshali to Perperikon, so technically you can walk it. :)

Comment: it's actually 15km from Kardzali, near the village Gorna Krepost

Comment: As I said.  If one is to believe Google.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are no direct buses to Perperikon.
 I could find only a [daily busline](http://hipo2.no-ip.biz/pero/?p=partners&pp=station) from Haskovo (Хасково) to Kardzali (Кърджали) via Stremtsi (Стремци), but the Problem is that Stremtsi is 8km from Perperikon (1-2 hours walking) [image: stremtsi-perperikon]
Onother way to visit Perperikon is to take a taxi from Kardzali. At the moment the taxi rate is about 0.60 BGN/km (about 0.30 EUR), the distance is about 20km, so it would cost about 7 EUR or even less if you try to deal with the taxi driver.

Comment: good question would be how are you going to return to Kardzali? I suspect the taxi operators will not be very keen on the idea to book a cab for the return route